# Динамические таблицы при помощи Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть данные в виде:

```
var tag = function(title, color) {
    return { 
        title: title,
        color: color
        };
    },row = function(title, date, location, trainer, places, tags){
    return { 
        title: title,
        date: date,
        location: location,
        trainer: trainer,
        places: places,
        tags: tags
    }
};

$scope.tags1 = [
            tag("#java", "info"),
            tag("#c++", "default")
        ];
$scope.tags2 = [
            tag("#js", "danger")
        ];
$scope.tags3 = [
            tag("#sql", "success")
        ];

$scope.rows = [
            row("Back-end", "25.05.2012", "234", "Yaroshevich", "12/15", $scope.tags1),
            row("Front-end", "28.05.2014", "243", "Shchaurouski", "10/15", $scope.tags2),
            row("SQL", "05.08.1999", "145", "Romashko", "1/15", $scope.tags3),
        ];
```

Необходимо отобразить их в виде таблицы:

```
<tbody>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         ...
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Вот как делаю я:

Контроллер

```
$scope.tableRows = $scope.rows.map(function(row) {
    var html = "<td>" + row.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + row.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + row.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + row.trainer + "</td>" + "<td>" + row.places + "</td>";
    var s = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    return s;
});
```

html

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
         <p ng-bind-html="tableRows[$index]"></p>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Вопрос: что не так, и что сделать, чтобы было так?

Comment: Как минимум у Вас "что-то не то" в методе `map` происходит. Вы куда-то передаете `html`, при этом в самой функции эта переменная создается каждый раз сначала. И ещё очень странно, что Вы пытаетесь куда-то вернуть `s`... Ну и такой код принято в директивы писать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечающие были правы: "Все не так". Решил использовать ng-table https://github.com/esvit/ng-table . Предельно простая директива. Привожу пример кода:

```
<table ng-class="'table table-bordered table-striped table-hover'" ng-table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="training in trainings">
                            <td data-title="'Title'">{{training.title}}</td>
                            <td data-title="'Date'">{{training.date}}</td>
                            <td data-title="'Location'">{{training.location}}</td>
                            <td data-title="'Trainer name'">{{training.trainerName}}</td>
                            <td data-title="'Places'">{{training.places}}</td>
                            <td data-title="'Tags'">{{training.tags}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

И js (с зависимостью ngTable):

```
 $scope.trainings = [{
    title: 'Front-end',
    date: '5 May 2015',
    location: '243',
    trainerName: 'Shchaurouski',
    places: '10/15',
    time: '14:00',
    tags: 'java js'
}, {
    title: 'Front-end',
    date: '5 Jan 2015',
    location: '243',
    trainerName: 'Shchaurouski',
    places: '10/15',
    time: '14:00',
    tags: 'java js'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да всё не так. Надо не html в контроллере собирать, а использовать `ng-repeat` и нужный шаблон в разметке.